# Why does my neutral read 115v with respect to ground?

Tags: electrical

In a receptacle box I have two 12/2 wires untied. One reads dead (both hot and neutral) the other reads 0.1 volts from hot to neutral but it reads 115v from hot to ground and also 115v from neutral to ground. What is the problem?

Comment: It would seem that both the hot and neutral of the one 12/2 are connected in the panel to the same leg if they run directly to the panel or if they run to another box connected to a hot lead there.  Have you looked for a 12/2 in you panel with two leads tied to a breaker?

Answer (score 1):

The dead wire was probably intended to tie into the live wire and head on down the line. 
Someone probably had a “brilliant “ idea to use the neutral as power and the ground as neutral. While it will give you power it is of course very dangerous.  Look in the panel and see if there is a white wire going to a circuit breaker. Most likely the splice was made in a junction box somewhere.